# Simple getElementbyId not working in Safari but Chrome works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I Have the Following AJAX Requests below that will work in chrome but not safari? I thought Chrome uses the Safari HTML. My Javascript Console has no errors on both safari and chrome. The First submit() function checks for duplicate entries and if no duplicate entries the second ajax submits the data. Everything works in Chrome but not Safari. Any Suggestions?

```
    function submit() {
        var bin = document.getElementById("bin_number").value;
        var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
        document.getElementById("alert").className = '';
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: '?a=ajax_check_scan_to_bin&bin='+bin+'&barcode='+barcode+'',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                if(data > 0) {
                    document.getElementById("form-group-"+id).className = 'form-group has-error  has-feedback';
                    document.getElementById("alert").className = 'alert alert-danger';
                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = 'This Barcode and Bin have Been Scanned Already';

                } else {
                    document.getElementById("submit-btn").className = 'btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success';
                    submit_form();    
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('some error happened');
            }
        }); 
    }      

function submit_form(){
            var bin = document.getElementById("bin_number").value;
            var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
                             $.ajax({
                            url: '?a=post_scantobin&bin_number='+bin+'&barcode='+barcode+'',
                            type: 'GET',
                            contentType: "text",
                            dataType: "text",
                            success: function(data){
                                if(data == '0') {
                                        document.getElementById("alert").className = 'alert alert-warning';
                                        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = 'Transaction Entered - Unable to Load into External Database';
                                } else if (data == '1') {
                                    document.getElementById("alert").className = 'alert alert-success';
                                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = 'Transaction Entered Successfully';
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById("alert").className = 'alert alert-danger';
                                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = data;
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert('some error happened');
                            }
                        });    
        }
    </script>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 column">
                <div class="" id='alert' role="alert"></div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-bin">
                         <label for="bin_number" class='control-label'>Scanning to Bin</label><input onchange="check('bin');" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="bin_number" id="bin_number" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id='form-group-barcode'>
                         <label for="barcode" class='control-label'>Item Barcode:</label><input onchange="check('barcode');" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="barcode" id="barcode" />
                    </div>
                    <button id="submit-btn" type="button" onblur="submit();" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What part does not work?

Comment: No Errors in Chrome and in Safari in the js console

Comment: Seems strange to use blur on a button. Add a breakpoint, walk through the code see if it is called.

Comment: Thats it! I'm not sure why i but blur on that button. Thank You!

Comment: Thats Strange now that chrome accepted the onblur as a click.